# Magento 2 How to Customize Checkout with adding login and signup page

Tags: magento2.2, onepage-checkout, login, register

I have worked on a Magento 2.2.6 version. I want the Horizontal Checkout please see the following screenshot. I also want the first step login and signup.[image]

Thanks in advance